# Selecting an item in select(dropdown) box using php

Tags: php

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<select name="select">

<?php

foreach($stock as $key => $value):
echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>'; 

endforeach;

?>
<option selected="selected" value="<?php echo $search; ?>"><?php echo $search; ?> </option>
</select>
```

This code adds a new value to the select box at last. But I need to select a value which is already present in the select box.

Eg, It contains a,b,c,d

I need to select c, but when i use this code it becomes a,b,c,d,c and the last "c" is selected.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Would you dont mind posting your complete code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your loop if the value matches the search.  So instead of:

```
<?php

foreach($stock as $key => $value):
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>'; 
endforeach;

?>
```

Do:

```
<?php
foreach($stock as $key => $value) 
{
   if($search == $value)
       echo '<option value="'.$value.'" selected="selected">'.$value.'</option>';
   else
       echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>'; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<select name="select">

<?php
$q = "";
foreach($stock as $key => $value):

 if($search = $value ){  
  $p = '<option selected="selected" value="'.$search.'">'.$search.'</option>';
 }
  $q = .'<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>'; 

endforeach;

?>
echo $p;
echo $q;
```

Comment: All that will do is put the selected option as the first item instead of the last, still leaving a second duplicate option in the list

Comment: That is a more correct answer, but overkill.  There isn't need to assign to two separate variables (technically any as they aren't using any output buffering)

Answer (score 0):

it will help

```
<select name="select">
<?php
  foreach($stock as $key => $value)
  {
    // This test printing value
    $option_selected = "";
    if($search == $value){ 
        $option_selected = 'selected="selected"'; 
    }

    echo '<option value="'.$value.'" '.$option_selected.'>'.$value.'</option>'; 
  }
?>  
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<select name="selectu">
        <?php
        $html = '';
        $html1 = '';
        $html2 = '';
        foreach ($stock as $key => $value):
            if ($value == $search):
                $html1 = '<option  value="' . $value . '" selected="selected">' . $value . '</option>';
            else:
                $html2 .= '<option  value="' . $value . '" >' . $value . '</option>';
            endif;
        endforeach;
        echo $html = $html1 . $html2;
        ?>

    </select>
```